# Whitelist Azure Database Migration Services on Alibaba

Tags: azure

I have Azure Database Migration Services. I know that Azure Database Migration Service does not have public IP. I also know that I need to enable Site-to-Site or ExpressRoute to Migrate from another cloud provider. And also, there is alternative to use NAT gateway to translate the Azure DMS private IP to Public.

I want to whitelist url/fqdn/ip address Azure Database Migration Service inside Alibaba Cloud ApsaraDB RDS for Azure Database Migration to reach the DB at Alibaba.

How can I make Azure Database Migration Service can be whitelist on Alibaba cloud?

Comment: I solved this problem, use a NAT gateway to communicate with the Alibaba ApsaraDB RDS. by whitelisting NAT publip IP an DMS Private IP.